# Submit offline data to Firestore on app start

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My users submit data to Firestore while offline. If the app remains in memory and regains an internet connection, the data will be uploaded.
If the app is killed, the previously submitted data will only be synced once new data is submitted to the database, almost like unclogging a pipe

This is how I'm submitting the data:

```
Future<Null> createFish(Fish _fish) async {

    var dataMap = Map<String, dynamic>();
    dataMap['userEmail'] = _fish.userEmail;
    dataMap['species'] = _fish.species;
    dataMap['location'] = _fish.location;

    Firestore.instance.collection('fish').add(dataMap);
}
```

My intended result is that even after data is submitted while offline, and the app is subsequently killed (either by the OS or the user) the data will be synced once the app is opened again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore will synchronize the local changes to the server, once it restores its connection. This happens the first time you access data from Firestore, either by reading it or by writing it. You might want to perform a small dummy read/write when the app is starting.

Comment: That's a great idea and a really good tip thank you! I'll try that and get back to you / mark your answer as accepted if it works

Comment: Yup, this was a nice simple solution. Everything is working as intended now, thank you!